# Binomial Hypothesis Test Segmentation For Webpage A/B Testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution, ab-test

**My Question**: Is `page1` performance better or worse than `page2` performance? Which page would you switch traffic to?

**More Context**

Imagine you have two website pages (page1, page2) that you are sending website traffic to.

On a **macro** level, if I compare `page1` `Conv. Rate` against `page2` `Conv. Rate`, **`page1`** is statistically better.  But, if I segment the data, `page2` **in every scenario has the better `Conv. Rate`**.

`74.319%` (819/1102) of total overall `Conversions` come from `Campaign2` > `https://www.website.com/page1` (second table). Is this skewing the results?

`Conv. Rate = Conversions / Clicks`

**Conversions** == success

**Clicks** == Trial

```
                               Clicks  Conversions    CPA  Conv. Rate
URL                                                                  
https://www.website.com/page1   17880          893  11.70      0.0499*
https://www.website.com/page2    7582          209  26.22      0.0276
Total                           25462         1102  14.45      0.0433
```

If I segment the `URL` by `Campaign`, `page2` has a better `Conv. Rate` for `Campaign1`, no statistically significant winner for `Campaign2` yet.

```
                                         Clicks  Conversions    CPA  Conv. Rate
Campaign  URL                                                                  
Campaign1 https://www.website.com/page1   12134           74  94.89      0.0061
          https://www.website.com/page2    7044          129  39.04      0.0183*
Campaign2 https://www.website.com/page1    5746          819   4.18      0.1425?
          https://www.website.com/page2     538           80   5.53      0.1487?
Total                                     25462         1102  14.45      0.0433
```

Then if I segment further:

```
                                                 Clicks  Conversions     CPA  Conv. Rate
Source  Campaign  URL                                                                   
Source1 Campaign1 https://www.website.com/page1    4836           43   66.81      0.0089
                  https://www.website.com/page2    1567           50   20.54      0.0319*
        Campaign2 https://www.website.com/page1    5029          772    3.70      0.1535?
                  https://www.website.com/page2     202           36    2.60      0.1782?
Source2 Campaign1 https://www.website.com/page1    7298           31  133.85      0.0042
                  https://www.website.com/page2    5477           79   50.76      0.0144*
        Campaign2 https://www.website.com/page1     717           47   12.15      0.0656
                  https://www.website.com/page2     336           44    7.93      0.1310*
Total                                             25462         1102   14.45      0.0433
```